# Phone field and mobile phone fields are showing duplicate data

Tags: leads

I have 2 different fields on lead details page

1. Phone
2. Mobile phone

What ever phone number I enter on the  phone field, duplicates same on the mobile phone field.How do I stop this from happeneing

Comment: This is likely due to automation on the Lead -- check for triggers, workflow rules, process builders, and/or Flows that replicate the `Lead.Phone` to `Lead.Mobile`